String compareTo() in java
Consider:
String s1 = "ABc";
String s2 = "abc";
System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));

On which basis the output will be -32 if only the first character decimal value of s1 and s2 are compared? Is this the correct way?
If String contains more than 1 character, then we should compare each character, but compareTo() method only compares the first character. Isn’t this a bug?

This is explained in the documentation. Also, why do you want to compare more characters when the first characters are already different?

I don't see a question here?

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and clarify your issue, [edit]ing your question to add an actual question.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. How can you know which characters it compares and which not? In any case comparing the first character of each string, A with a, suffices for knowing that a negative value must be returned. Which is all that the documentation promises us. Only if the first chars are the same (say, A and A), the method would need to look at the second char of each string.

Also which output had you expected? As mentioned, all the documentation promises is some negative value, so -438756435 and -1 would both have been correct.

@Anonymous Check the documentation. It explains how the specific value returned is calculated.

Curious. When closely reading, deep down in the text you are correct. @OldDogProgrammer How useless.

"...then on which basis the output will be -32" The char primitive is an integer type. You can do arithmetic with it. What output do you get if you run this code: char au = 'A', al = 'a'; System.out.println (au - al); ? Does that result agree with the documentation linked to in the comment from Sweeper?

compareTo guarantees that it returns some negative number if s1 comes before s2 in lexicographic order.
When comparing "apple" and "banana", for example, you only need to look at the first character to determine that "apple" comes before "banana", because a comes before b.

That is guaranteed by interface Comparable, which String does implement.  But, you could improve the answer by including a response to this part of the O/P's question: "On which basis the output will be -32".

@OldDogProgrammer, I disagree.  I think knowing why the answer will be -32 is actively harmful, as it's not something you should use, care about, or depend on in any way, and I'd strongly consider down voting any answer that did explain that.

That's reasonable. But, I have to wonder if whoever wrote the documentation for String#compareTo method agrees, since the documentation does describe how non-zero results are calculated.
